# Assigning background-color & border-color to buttons dynamically in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor, ng-class

I have an array of colors,

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
```

Also, I have an array like this

```
demo = ['de1', 'de2', 'de3', 'de4', 'de5', 'de6', 'de7', 'de8', 'de9', 'de10', 'de11', 'de12', 'de13', 'de14']
```

and so on, which is dynamic, which I get in response from an API call from which I'm preparing buttons.

I need to assign the `background-color` and `border-color` from the `colors []` to each element in `demo []` in the same order.
Need help on this.

TIA

Comment: can you please elaborate more with actual code sample i.e., in terms of the tags you used in this post ngfor, ng-class. I can't understand exactly what you want, can't understand what the elements in demo array refer to. Are these static ids of button?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you not have elements in your array demo (your array is an array of strings)

```
<!--imagine an array of "items"-->
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  .....
</div>
```

You can then use some like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
  <div [style.color]="colors[i%5]">I'm in color {{colors[i%5]}}</div>
</div>
```

You can also use ViewChildren

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
  <div #dd>I'm in color {{colors[i%5]}}</div>
</div>
```

And in your .ts

```
@ViewChildren('dd') items:QueryList<ElementRef>
ngAfterViewInit()
{
   this.items.forEach((x:ElementRef,i:number)=>{
          x.nativeElement.style.color=this.colors[i%5]
   })
}
```